# Why can't I use the return from an insertAfter as a regular jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to insert a link after form elements to clear them.

This demo code with headings doesn't work:

```
h2 = $('h2');
clickytest = $('<a href="#" class="clicky">click me</a>').insertAfter(h2).click(function() {
  $(this).append('foo');
});
```

But this does:

```
h2 = $('h2');
clickytest = $('<a href="#" class="clicky">click me</a>').insertAfter(h2);
$('a.clicky').click(function() {
  $(this).append('foo');
});
```

The only difference is I've gone back and re-selected the new elements, rather than use what insertAfter returns.

If on the other hand there is only *one* H2 in the whole document, then the first version works. What's going on? I've tried playing with each() but I'm not sure exactly what jQuery is doing here.

Comment: I tried editing, but it changed things more than I expected. I suspect your code appears quite differently to what you intended. The best way to format is by indenting code by four spaces, not with <code> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick to attaching your event handlers to the elements before moving them, since some attachment methods differ on which context they return. Attach the click before moving on for it to always work, like this:

```
$('<a href="#" class="clicky">click me</a>').click(function() {
  $(this).append('foo');
}).insertAfter('h2');​
```

[See here for a working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6EBkd/) (multiple `<h2>` elements)